# After publishing a beta to the windows store, my mobileservicesynctable does not sync

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

I just published a beta to the windows store for my UWP.  Everything works fine when I side load the app.  Release/Debug both work in this fashion.  However, the exact same version when downloaded from the windows store does not sync.  The changes are stored to the local database fine enough.  However, when the beta is downloaded using a promotional code, the sync function just doesn't work when it comes to pushing data (pulls still work).  No errors are being returned, the sync counter increases they just do not push any data during a sync.  I am assuming this is yet ANOTHER gotcha with authentication (because there havent been enough)...but where to start, when everything works fine in the shop?!  I have tried resetting the local datastore to a fresh db.  I am able to download the data again, and still...no push occurs.  This is an online/offline/authenticated azure mobile service app.  The only difference between the operational version, and the broken one....is that the working versions are side loaded, and the broken one is coming from the store.  Any ideas??

Comment: I wrapped the entire sync function with a try/catch looking for MobileServicePushFailedException and published again...no reaction or error was produced by the catch.  Still no push

Comment: Tried catching any Exceptions, nothing...

Comment: Further investigation into this problem reveals that the pending operations is returning a -1 on startup...I suspect that the answer lies here somehow, yet the MSDN docs do not mention what a -1 represents.  Anyone know???

Comment: Also...this error occurs in release versions of the app, not just the windows store download...debug versions work as intented